# Selecting only when specific values exist in another select query

Tags: mysql, select

A bit of a noob question, but would appreciate the help.

I want to use the result of one select statement in a different one in a specific way.

The first select statemnent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM customers WHERE country = 'Neverland';
```

The result will be a one-column table with distinct IDs.
Now I want to select all these IDs from a different table.

```
SELECT * FROM shipments WHERE [the id is contained within the first select statement]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer would be to combine both queries, directly, using subqueries (`IN`). So, assuming the column on shipments is also called id (substitute it with the real name, if different):

```
SELECT * 
FROM shipments 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT id 
              FROM customers 
              WHERE country = 'Neverland')
```

It may be nice to learn a bit about `JOIN`s, while those may seem more complicated at first, they may have in some cases a better query plan or logically less complex once you learn about those:

```
SELECT *
FROM shipments
JOIN customers
ON shipments.id = customers.id
WHERE shipments.country = 'Neverland'
```

(again, you may need to adapt it to the particular column names, and cardinality relation- show no duplicate shipments, etc.).